# Retrieve JSON element using JsonPath- Jayway

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jayway

I have a below JSON. I want to get **pin code where street =='abc strt.'** 
I am using Jaway to achieve this.

```
{
  "studentId": "10001",
  "studentSection": "A",
  "address": [
    {
      "street": "abc strt.",
      "pincode": "00000000"
    },
    {
      "street": "xzy strt.",
      "pincode": "1111111"
    },
    {
      "street": "678 strt.",
      "pincode": "8765"
    },
    {
      "street": "ity strt.",
      "pincode": "234567"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
List<String> = result = JsonPath.read(json, "$.['address'].[?@.street == 'abc strt.'].pincode");
```

JayWay XPath:  `$.['address'].[?@.street == 'abc strt.'].pincode`, it's returning `List<String>`.

The above query will always return a single value, but due to the return type as `List<String>`, I have to use value as `list.get(0)`.

Is there a way to return String instead of List??


Also, I have 10 more queries, which I have to execute on the same JSON. Should I query once & use the result, or can I query 10 times and use the result. What is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Jayway Jsonpath docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath),

> Jayway JsonPath is a Java port of Stefan Goessner JsonPath implementation.

And as per [Stefan Goessner JsonPath docs](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/),

> Please note, that the return value of jsonPath is an array, which is also a valid JSON structure. So you might want to apply jsonPath to the resulting structure again or use one of your favorite array methods as sort with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more doubt, is it a good practice to query the json multiple times, or query once & then use the result. For example, similar to the above query, I have 10 more queries. Should I combine them, or individually query is also good performance-wise?

Comment: I am not completely sure about the performance, may be you can give it a try - call combined query n number of times and call 10 different queries also n number of times each and measure the times.